Will this burn out the coil in the relay
I do not want my Natural Gas heater to turn on if either of my garage doors are open; and if one is opened up, I want the heater to shut off.  I have a garage door open/close reed switch installed on each garage door and I had originally simply had them in series with the heat call wire however the run was too long and was unreliable.  The below diagram is working flawless using a standard automotive relay.  I'm just wondering if the constant closed state of the garage doors is going to burn-out the coil in the relay?  Can I, or should I limit the current?


The make, model and parameters of the relay are unknown. Therefore, it's impossible to say if it is rated for constant use or will it burn out.

Is the relay rated for continuous operation, or intermittent? There are ways to reduce the holding current if needed.

can you use a solid state relay instead? those burn very little power... If the signal is DC, you can even use a mosfet.

If the relay is rated for 12V having it energized all the time should not be a problem. The 12V coil resistance will be about 100 ohms typically; its current 120mA. I would be more concerned about the MTBF of the power supply, to be honest.
But for the heck of it, let's talk about ways to not have the relay coil burning up one-and-a-half watts all the time.
To do that we want to loop the thermostat through the relay NC contacts, so that the loop is connected when the relay is de-energized.
Do you have the option to use NO door switches (closed when no magnet, open when magnetized)? If so, you can change the setup to wire the door switches in parallel to the relay coil. Then when one of more switches closes on door open, the relay is energized, interrupting the thermostat loop.
If you must use NC door switches (closed when magnet), they can be made to work too. Wire them in series as you've shown, and add a transistor to drive the relay, like below (simulate it here):

If both door switches are closed, the transistor base is grounded and the transistor is off. Relay is de-energized, relay NC contacts are closed, thermostat loop is connected.
If one or both switches open, the 2.2k resistor pulls the transistor base up. Transistor turns on, energizes the relay, opens the NC contacts and disconnects thermostat loop.
A detail: the diode across the relay coil is a 'catch diode' to suppress the flyback voltage from the coil when its current is switched off. This prevents damage to the transistor.

If I wire the reed switches in parallel wouldn't that mean the heater woudl operate if ONE door was open?   Oh wait, I see.....

A side benefit of using the NC contact on the relay is that if something in the garage door magnet circuit breaks, it won't completely disable you heat

I was thinking if the 12V power fails the heater still works.

If continuous relay coil current is an issue, a simple solution is to add a capacitor, in parallel with a resistor, in series with the relay. This works because a DC relay has a far higher "pull-in" current than "holding" current. The capacitor provides an initial inrush current, which drops in a fraction of second to the value the resistor passes.
For example, that 12 VDC - rated relay might reliably pull-in at 10 V, and stay closed until the voltage drops to 5 VDC or less (the "drop-out" voltage).
You'd have to determine experimentally, but a starting point might be a 2,000 µF cap in parallel with a resistor about the same value as the DC resistance of the coil. Test to be sure the relay pulls in and drops out reliably.
This wouldn't hurt, and has the advantage of cutting power wastage.
